# Simple Content Search with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search, jquery-plugins

First of all this is how the script works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/7Rm8U/7/light/)

So, I want to make the plugin to search through images (thumbnails) by a attribute like "title" for example or something else.
Here is my markup : http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/KqCP5/embedded/result/
I can't make the script to search through that images, I know something is wrong, maybe I didn't put the correct path for

'searchList' : 'home_proj li',

'searchItem' : 'img'

The code below will activate the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.searchFilter').simpleContentSearch({
        'active' : 'searchBoxActive',
        'normal' : 'searchBoxNormal',
        'searchList' : 'home_proj li',
        'searchItem' : 'img'
    });
});
```

The 'searchList' setting specifies the content that will be searched. In this case it is searchable tr. Finally, the 'searchItem' setting allows to dive in and specify an individual element to search. In this case, I use 'td'.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can check also a live version for what I'm trying to achieve: [here](http://whiteandgold.ro/realty/)

Comment: Would it be easier to use jQuery.filter? http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `'searchList'` to `'home_proj ul li'`
and `'searchItem'` to `'a'` seems working.

For example, try `title="abc"` and search "abc"

---

First, `'searchList'` is the common type of the DOM object you want to filter.
So in your second markup, when you want to search a list of `<a>`, then you should set `'searchList'` as `'jThumbnailScroller a'`

Second, `'searchItem'` is the part of the DOM object you want to search on. The way this plugin does it, is that it searches the DOM object's `html()`, however if you want to search on `<img>`, it's not gonna work because its `html()` is empty. So if you really want to search on `<img>` title, you should set `'searchItem'` as `'img'`, and change this part of the plugin

`if (!elem.html().match(new RegExp('.*?' + query + '.*?', 'i')))`

to

`if (!elem.attr('title').match(new RegExp('.*?' + query + '.*?', 'i')))`

Comment: Any idea why it's not working with this [markup](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/gEFXh/) ? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Now I have another issue:

I have a jquery thumbnail scroller and for example if you scroll till the end of the 
thumbnails and then you search for "bedroom" you have to scroll back to the 
beginning to see the results. 

Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.
I can't post the code for thumbnails scroller here or on jsfiddle because it's pretty large.
You can check [here](http://whiteandgold.ro/livesearch) what I'm trying to say. 
Please give me some suggestions.
Thanks again!

Comment: @CristoceaCostel add a listener, so that whenever you type in something it will scroll to the top. Also, I think I've already answered your original question very well. I don't know why you are not accepting it. But that's fine. If you have new question, please write another post.

Comment: Sorry, now is accepted.  How exactly I can add a listenere I'm not so good at Javascript could you give me some suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: @CristoceaCostel check out this [tutorial](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) about adding events. Thank you for your accepting.. but like I said, please write another post if you have new question, I'm sure there will be lot of people willing to help you.